# How to select master page for a web page in web application ( VS 2008 )?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications, master-pages

I have a asp.net web application and I create a master page when i try to add new web page i can't find any option that allow me to set master page as in web site ... i just do it manually  ... **Is it any way to select master page during creating web page ??**

EDIT :I do it manually by add `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"` to page tag and make all html in `asp:Content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a **Web Content Form** instead of a **Web Form** you can select a master page at creation time.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `Page.MasterPageFile`

**EDIT:** I think I misunderstood, as Scoregraphic said, just add a new Content Page

Answer (score 0):

Create a "content page" and it should do the trick